# Download file through ActiveX in C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, download, activex

I have html that launches ActiveX to download a file.

Instead of using internet explorer to download the file, I want it done through C#/.NET

The HTML looks like this:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <OBJECT ID="o" CLASSID="CLSID:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" CODEBASE="https://YYYYYY/grTransferCtrl.cab#version=5,0,0,32">
        </OBJECT>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript FOR=window EVENT="onLoad()">

            On Error Resume Next

            o.Persist "AAA"
            o.Persist "BBB"
            o.Persist "CCC"

            bRetVal = o.Launch()
            If(Err.Number > 0 Or bRetVal = False) Then 
            msgbox "There was an error launching File Transfer Manager.",0,""
            End if

        </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
<BODY></BODY>
```

How can I launch the download straight from my C# application?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you making an ActiveX control in this day and age?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is `[WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)'

The following will do roughly what you want:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://YYYYYY/grTransferCtrl.cab#version=5,0,0,32");

//This is where you may need to add cookies and other header data for this to work.
//I would use fiddler to try and inspect the http requests sent by the control for this
//information
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
var response = request.GetResponse();

using (var file= response.GetResponseStream())
{
    //do something with the stream? save it?
}   
response.Close();
```

As an alternative you could create the ActiveX control in your application and just use it.  There are plenty of resources on the web for adding ActiveX controls to .NET forms applications, just unaware of what assumptions this particular control makes about it environment that may prevent that.

Comment: Your variable names are inconsistant and confusing.  (eg.  `request` vs. `imageRequest`)

Comment: This doesn't take into account the o.Persist("file_to_download_and_other_cookie_data")

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the System.Net.WebClient

```
Example:

public class Downloader
{
  public void DownloadFile()
  {
     using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
     {
         webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.stackoverflow.com/stacks.txt", @"c:\stacks.txt");
     }
  }
}
```